# SQL - how can I clean up corrupted html column?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, richtext

I have a table and one of the columns has html stored in it. Some of the data seems to be corrupted and has a lot of code that should be

```
<p></p>
```

but instead has:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;amp;gt;
```

What would be the best way to clean this? I've been able to identify around 200 rows usings:

```
select [procedure], * from table 
where [procedure] like '%;amp;%[!a-z]%'
or [procedure] like '%;gt;[a-z]%'
or [procedure] like '%;lt;[a-z]%'
```

Update:
An example of a bad cell is:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;amp;gt;This CR documents the ILO CRC meeting for units 2&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;3 on 9/17/14.&amp;amp;amp;lt;/p&amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;amp;gt;Management has been notified.&amp;amp;amp;lt;/p&amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;/p&amp;amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am leaning towards at the moment. I think it would also help to add a stored procedure or trigger until I can figure out how the users are inputting the data.

```
update table
set [procedure] = REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
[procedure], '&amp;gt;','>')
, '&amp;lt;','<')
, '&amp;quot;','"')
, '&nbsp;',' ')
, '&quot;', '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds most logical to do, if I understand your question correctly.

```
update tablename
set procedure = '<p></p>'
where [procedure] like '%;amp;%[!a-z]%'
  or [procedure] like '%;gt;[a-z]%'
  or [procedure] like '%;lt;[a-z]%'
```

Comment: The column contains more than just the paragraph tags. I should have elaborated more. It also contains a lot of other text. It just begins and ends with those tags.

Comment: What do you want to keep and what do you want to remove from that field? Can you provide an example of a relatively complex bad-case where you have lot of other text and an example of how you would like that field to look after cleanup?